# How do I know if com.uniquestudio.library.CircleCheckBox animation has finished?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm using [CircleCheckBox library](https://github.com/CoXier/CheckBox), and I'm trying to execute piece of code after check animation is finished.

```
<com.uniquestudio.library.CircleCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at this library and discovered that it`s not possible with this library, because it`s not provided there.